Computing $\|\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\|_1$ in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time for $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$ where $r\ge 2$ fixed
Let us consider some $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$, where $r\ll n$. When $r=1$, i.e., $\boldsymbol{X}$ is essentially a vector $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then we have
$$
\|\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^{\text{T}}\|_1=\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_1^2,
$$
which can be computed in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time. Here, $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the elementwise $\ell_1$-norm; e.g., $\|\boldsymbol{X}\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^r|x_{ij}|$. My question is as follows:

For fixed $r\ge 2$ (with $r\ll n$), is $\|\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\|_1$ still computable in time linear in $n$?

Indeed, a naive evaluation of $\|\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\|_1$ takes $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ time, where the low-rankness of $\boldsymbol{X}$, i.e., $r$, plays no role.
Some trivial observations:

When $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{R}_+^{n\times r}$ (i.e., nonnegative), we have
$$
\|\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}})_{ij}=\boldsymbol{1}_n^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{1}_n=\|\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{1}_n\|_2^2,
$$
which can be computed in $\mathcal{O}(nr)$ time; this is linear in $n$ for fixed $r$.
When we consider the (squared) Frobenius norm instead, we have
$$
\|\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\|_{\text{F}}^2=\operatorname{Tr}(\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}})=\operatorname{Tr}\left((\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{X})(\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\boldsymbol{X})\right),
$$
which can be computed in $\mathcal{O}(nr^2+r^3)$ time; this is linear in $n$ for fixed $r$.

By the way, if the answer to the question is negative, I would also like to ask if $\|\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{X}^{\text{T}}\|_1$ is computable in $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ time or something; here, $r$ is hidden in the complexity (as it is fixed). Many thanks in advance!

Consider $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$ as the collection of row vectors
$\boldsymbol{x}{1},\cdots,\boldsymbol{x}{n}\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times r}$.
If you know in advance that all the inner products $\boldsymbol{x}{i}\cdot \boldsymbol{x}{j}\geq 0$ for all $i,j$, there is an $O(n)$ algorithm. Of course, to check this condition requires $O(n^2)$ time.

I haven't put much thought into it, but it might be helpful to frame this as a linear programming problem. What you're doing is maximizing $\operatorname{Tr}[XX^TJ] = \operatorname{Tr}[X^TJX]$
subject to the constraint that the entries of $J$ are in $[-1,1]$.

@BenGrossmann Thanks for your suggestion. However, to my best knowledge, linear programming isn't something that is efficiently solvable; e.g., the best algorithm that I'm aware (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.11957) takes time about $\mathcal{O}(n^{2.38})$, where $n$ is the number of variables in the LP, and in the context here, the complexity can be $\mathcal{O}(n^{4.76})$.

@A.Kato Thanks for the observation. Although this condition still seems strong, it relaxes the nonnegativity condition pretty much.
